# How do I save output images using Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I am trying to run the following code from this repository for educational purposes.

https://github.com/UjjwalSaxena/Automold--Road-Augmentation-Library

I am using Jupiter notebook I plot the output running following code:

```
bright_images= am.brighten(images[0:6]) 
hp.visualize(bright_images)
```

and I get the following plot, which plots images into columns

I would like to save these output images separately, not attached together. 
my question is how do I save these images separately, each in the folder with their original size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The visualize function helps in displaying images easily without
>   requiring you to write the whole code.

If you dig in the source code, the library uses `cv2` aka `openCV` for images.

So your images are in `bright_images` and you can save images like so;

```
import cv2

i = 0
while i < len(bright_images) - 1:
    cv2.imwrite(f'path_to/image_{i}.png', bright_images[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: I added these lines when executing, it gives me errors. Do not you think cv2.cv has been removed in OpenCV3 and functions have changed? If so could you please edit your post? Error says :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv'

Comment: Is this better ?

Comment: The issue left is that the loop does not work well, it writes one image in a single image for 6 times.

Comment: My images are sequential and they are in order. When I run the code just process and write them randomly. I was wondering if you could please tell me how can I make saving images to be sequential and in order? I tried "    cv2.imwrite(path + '.jpg',  bright_images)"  but unfortunately does not work well.

Comment: As of now, they are saved in the order they are in bright_images.

Comment: I see I have to dig into the library.